# is there a syntax to call named overload operator functions directly

Tags: dart

Trying to invert a map and the following approach works fine:

```dart
  var x = { 'dart' : 'fun', 'dentist' : 'painful', };
  var xInv = x.keys.fold({}, (prev, elm) { prev[x[elm]] = elm; return prev; });
```

Is there a syntax to call 'operator[]=( , )' directly so you could also use cascades? Something like these which do not work:

```dart
  var xInv = x.keys.fold({}, (prev, elm) => prev..'operator[]='(x[k], k));
  var xInv = x.keys.fold({}, (prev, elm) => prev..operator[]=(x[k], k));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what you want?

```dart
Map<String,String> xInv2 = x.keys.fold({}, 
    (Map<String,String> prev, String elm) => prev..[x[elm]] = elm);
```

Creates the same result as your first example with the return statement.

(You don't have to add to add the type annotations though. It's just easier for me to grasp the intention of the code)

Comment: Just what I was looking for - did not know how to apply the syntax.